# Can I set the SHIFT-S hotkey back to the standard menu from this pie menu?

Tags: interface, pie-menu

The <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  pie menu in 2.8 drives me nuts. Sometimes it appears as it should and other times it flashes on and disappears. I can get it to stay by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> until I've made the selection and timed my click with the release of the keys.

As often as not I get the timing wrong and have to do it again. How can I either get the old list menu back, or fix the pie menu to actually stay long enough to make a selection?

Comment: You don't have to hold it, just press shift-s once.

Comment: you could also put it in the Q menu (Quick Favorites): Go in the horizontal menu bar > Object > Snap, right click to add to Quick Favorites (to remove, same thing except you'll have access to the remove function once you'll right click). Now you just need to press Q and you'll have access to the snap functions.

Comment: Arthur, that's exactly the problem - if I don't hold the keys the menu disappears (sometimes).

Comment: Some people try to press both keys at the same time. Hold down Shift, then press and release S and then release Shift. The menu should stay open as you move the mouse around all menu options, until you click the mouse.